# Copy Data from Trailing Months

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where data is being captured on daily basis.
For example: Columns are account, fundnumber, amount, date.
Suppose data is being captured till 31 Dec, 2020 and next data is present from 1st March, 2021.
Now, my requirement is I want to fill data from 1st Jan, 2021 to 28th Feb, 2021 from last entered data i.e. from 31st Dec, 2020.
I want to copy data from 31st Dec, 2020 and fill in 1st Jan, 2021 to 28th Feb.

Is it possible?
Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by running a while loop

```
DECLARE @currentDate Date;
set @currentDate = '2021-01-01'
WHILE @currentDate <= '2021-02-28' 
BEGIN
    insert into yourtable(account, fundnumber, amount, date) select account, fundnumber, amount, @currentDate from yourtable where date='2020-12-31'
    SET @currentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @currentDate)
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the promt reply.
Is there any way where we can write select query where the trailing data will get copied to mentioned Date(01/01/2021 to 28/02/2021) and we get all the details in one go?